# C# Socket.Receive() malfunctions when TCP package is larger than MTU

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I'm using C# Socket class to send/receive TCP messages to/from our server by short connection. The pseudo-code (exclude some false tolerant logic to make it clear) is as followings.

```
class MyTCPClient {
    private Socket mSocket;

    MyTCPClient() {
        mSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    }

    void Connect(ipEndpoint, sendTimeOut, receiveTimeOut) {
        mSocket.Connect(ipEndpoint);
        mSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.SendTimeout, sendTimeOut);
        mSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReceiveTimeout, receiveTimeOut);
    }

    void Send(msg) {
        mSocket.Send(msg);
    }

    void Receive(data) {
        ByteStreamWriter bsw = new ByteStreamWriter();
        int totalLen = 0;
        while (true) {
            byte[] temp = new byte[1024];
            int len = mSocket.Receive(temp, SocketFlags.None);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);  // This is the weirdest part
            if (len <= 0) break;
            totalLen += len;
            bsw.WriteBytes(temp);
        }
        byte[] buff = bsw.GetBuffer();
        data = new byte[totalLen];
        Array.Copy(buff, 0, data, 0, totalLen);
    }

    ~MyTCPClient() {
        mSocket.Close();
    }
}
```

I was using this class to request the same message from our server several times by short connection, and the following things occurred (only when the message size was larger than one MTU -- 1500 bytes).

1. If the "Sleep(50)" was commented out, the most of the times (90%) I received wrong "data", specifically to say, the "totalLen" was right, but the "data" was wrong.
2. If I replaced "Sleep(50)" to "Sleep(10)", about half of the times I received wrong "data", and "totalLen" was also right always.
3. If I used "Sleep(50)", occasionally, I received wrong "data".

I can guarantee that, every time, our server sent the right data, and the client received the right data too at TCP layer (I used WireShark to monitor all messages through the port I used). Is there anyone who can help to answer why my C# code cannot get the right data?

Also, if I use mSocket.Available instead of the return value of Socket.Receive() to judge the while loop, I would always get the right data and data length...

Comment: What does *wrong data* mean? You get a lot of zero's? or garbage? And where does that ByteStreamWriter come from? Is that a BinaryWriter?

Comment: You don't really understand how TCP operates.  TCP breaks messages into datagrams with max size ~`1500 bytes.  The Net library uses timers so datagrams can get futher split or combined.  TCP also sends messages with zero bytes which is used as a keep-alive so the connection doesn't close.  So when sending messages you must have a terminator for each message.  You can use a combination of 3 techniques : 1) ASCII : Terminate with fixed char like '`\' 2)Ascii or Binary : Add length to beginning of message 3) Ascii or Binary : Fixed length message.  Receive needs to read message until end is found

Comment: @rene Sorry, I didn't express very clearly. Wrong data mean garbage, and the garbage exactly started from the first byte of the second TCP datagram every time. And the ByteStreamWriter is a very simple BinaryWriter, I can guarantee it worked as expected.

Comment: @jdweng Sorry that I didn't give enough info I think. I was using short connection every time, so I assumed I would receive 0 only when our server close the connection and that also meant one message was finished receiving.

Comment: Unrelated: Your class should not have a finalizer. You might want to read up on finalizer best practices.

Answer (score 2):

You don't truncate `temp` to `len` bytes before writing it. All the bytes after `len` in `temp` have not been filled with current data and thus contain nonsensical, stale date.

When copying to another stream you could use `stream.Write(temp, 0, len)`